# The Prydwen map marker

Tags: fallout-4

I have noticed more and more that when I highlight the Prydwen, it shows the stats of a settlement. Can the Prydwen be used as a settlement?

Answer (score 2):

The prydwen cannot be used as a settlement but supply lines can be sent there. They will end up at the airport instead however. At the airport there is also a workbench, but it can only be used for crafting in a certain story mission and will not function like any other settlement.

Comment: how can i send settlers there? it does not highlight on the supply line menu for settlers

Comment: I'm not sure about the how as I haven't tried myself. Most of the information I was reading [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164594-fallout-4/72880805).

Comment: @Sparta270 Send the settler to Boston Airport, not the Prydwen. The airport is a regular settlement in most respects, but not all.